# Powershell Reset Windows Update

Tags: powershell, windows-update

I currently installed a fresh official Windows 7 Ultimate on my MacbookPro with BootCamp.

Everything is running good except Windows Update. Stuck on Searching for updates..

So I made a lot of google searches (for about 4 hours now) and I tried many things such as the FixIt tools from MS and other tricks but nothing is working.

Now i'm trying this:
http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/372790-very-high-memory-sometimes-cpu-usage-svchost-exe-up-1-gb-post3095241.html#post3095241

I'm now at using PowerShell and entering this command line:

```
sc.exe sdset bits D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
```

I always get this error:

```
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:23
+ sc.exe sdset bits D:(A <<<< ;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRS
DRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseParenToken:TokenId) [], Paren
   tContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInExpression
    enter code here
```

I took a look at the commande line and I dont see any missing ')', and made some other google search for this command line from other websites and always give the same error

Whats wrong..!?

**Update:**

I tried this without success (same error)

```
$str = "sc.exe sdset bits D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)"

Invoke-Expression $str
```

Comment: Could it be that PowerShell is inserting a line break after 80 characters?

Comment: If thats the reason.. why every command line found on google are same as this one in the same procedure, and everyone seems to be able to apply it ? 

How to get the PS not break the cmd line !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution and its to type the command as follow:

```
CMD /C "sc.exe sdset bits D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)"
```

Comment: I think the `;` in your command was throwing it off. You could also have used `Invoke-Expression -Command "..."`

Answer (score 0):

When I put quotes around the entire command, the dos prompt removed the quote marks, and returned the result. Putting the quotes around the long parameter list, i.e., doing this:

sc.exe sdset bits "D:(A;; [snip] ;;PU)"

resulted in the Dos Prompt executing giving the message Success.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell does not play well with DOS executable files and their arguments.

Try using:

```
Start-Process sc.exe -ArgumentList 'sdset bits D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is invoking DOS use single quotes around the DOS command and add double quotes around the ACL "D:(A;;......;;PU)".  It would look like this

`Invoke-Expression -Command 'sc.exe sdset bits "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;AU)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;PU)"'`